# Home Server Stopped Routing to IP

Tags: debian, apache-virtualhost

I have set up an apache server on Debian.  I have [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) pointing to my home IP for my subdomains.  unraid.mydomain.com.  This has been working up until about a week ago.  Now when I am connected to my wifi locally I am unable to access the sites.  I get what appears to be the router login page but it's restricted.  I assume router login due to the login.htm page it is trying.  My apache file is setup correctly I assume as it was always working before.   What do I need to look at to fix this so that if I'm home I can still access unraid.mydomain.com?  Why would this stop working suddenly with no changes?  I have been running this on a debian box that i have not turned off or touched in months.

[image]

I also setup nginx on my unraid server and that has the same results.

[image]

Off wifi this works just fine.  My router is a fios router that points to the correct ip on port 80

Comment: This is an issue with your Web Server. The error you are seeing is a 403 forbidden which means that you are reaching the server but you are not allowed to open that file. It could be that after an update permissions on the root directory changed. I would suggest that you look at your application's permissions and go from there.

Comment: The odd thing is the page it is trying to open is not on my server.   It is the router login page. if i define the port in the URL it opens the correct page. All ports are forwarded correctly in my router networking page.

Comment: Also this box hasnt been updated in a year now.  Also, the last SSH session before this issue was 5 months 8 days ago.  I have blocked all automatic updates so i dont run into issues.  This is bizarre to say the least.  The Verizon Fios router throws this error because of the URL trying to access it.